# Team Foundation Server 2010 broken after service account password change

Tags: .net, tfs

Team Foundation Server 2010 is installed in a server which is member of a domain.

Both domain controller and member are Windows Server 2008.

Today, the Windows Server where Team Foundation Server is installed in prompted to change **domain controller's built-in administrator account** because this user has password expiration (too bad) following domain policy.

Since this moment, I've Team Foundation 2010 broken.

**I'm getting TF30063 *unauthorized access*** errors in the client-side, and team members can't checkout files, I can't drop or add team members and other things.

I've tried these solutions so far:

- Setting domain controller's administrator account again from TFS Administration Console.
- Turn back password to the original one, and setting again it in TFS Administration Console.
- Setting new password on IIS Application Pools.
- Setting old password on IIS Application Pools and in TFS Administration Console.
- Reparing TFS 2010 using its setup and reboot.
- Reboot IIS.
- ...

How can I solve this situation? For now, I've disabled password expiration for this administrator account so this isn't going to happen in the future, but I need to get TFS 2010 working again.

Thank for your effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've solved this backing up TFS's databases and reinstalling TFS 2010 from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

There are two points where the password of the TFS user has to be changed:

1. The password of the *Microsoft Team Foundation Server Application Pool* in the *IIS Manager*
2. The password of the *TFS Applications*. This has to be changed via the *Team Foundation Server Administration Console*. The password has to be entered as well in *Application Tier Summary* as in *Reporting Services Summary*.

Comment: Thank you the info, but you may notice your solutions are included in my own question, these have been tried already. In the other hand, I don't have Reporting Services, I'm only using TFS for task management and source control. I've tried to change TFS service account password using the command-line utility too. No way, thank you again.